# Dose TLS check certificate expiration even after the hand shake?

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

If TLS session created by using OpenSSL API then that check the certificate expiration in the handshake stage. Let's assume that the certificate gets expired after completing the handshake but before terminate the session (For long-lasting TLS session). Then does it detect by the OpenSSL?

(As a side note; Dose TLS regenerate the session key even after the handshake stage ?)

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. The certificate is checked at the beginning of the handshake, and after that it does not come into play (until the connection is ended and a new one is started from scratch). Keys are changed during the exchanges, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-5.5 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#section-7.1   But that key is typically not related to the certificate in any way.

Comment: (1) Not until the next full handshake, (2) Yes.